# How to know if app been downloaded user's device?

Tags: android, ios, permissions

I have native Android app and iOS app.

I need to implement a UI that differentiates between users who have a specific app and users who don't.

Is it possible to access information about whether a user has downloaded a specific app on Android or iOS?

Comment: What kind of UI do you plan to have, web, other app, ...?

Comment: On iOS, if the app has a custom url scheme, you can query to see if there is an app installed that can open that url scheme. It may or may not be the app you are checking for; any app can register any url scheme.  You can't check for a specific app any other way for privacy reasons

Comment: @meaning-matters - if user has a mobile id app, i will request authentication with that app, otherwise request a id picture.

Comment: @Paulw11 - thanks paul